# TYPO3 - Including content elements in extensions

Tags: php, typo3

Im building a new kickstarter app, and I have to edit for the first time the extension in PHP, and **not in Typoscript**, so im unsure.

Im using the "normal" column for the content of the page. In this I have my new plugin. On other column I have some content that I want to render only under certain conditions. How can I make that my plugin outputs the content of the Right Column?

Comment: You are talking about frontend or backend? If you have three columns in the backend, the records will have different values in colPos. But you could render them all in the frontend in one column. Your question is not clear enough!

Comment: Ive tried to clear it up a little. Im using the Right column to store some content elements that I dont want to show every time. Just when the conditions met in my extension are true. But I dont know how to make that my extension outputs the contents of the Right Column.

Comment: did you tried my code? IMHO it is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know, if i understand you right. You want to check the condition in your extension?

```
# TypoScript:
# pass the configuration which content should be shown to your extension
plugin.tx_yourextension_pi1.contentToShow < styles.content.getRight

# in your extension:
if (some conditions) {
  $content = $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle($conf['contentToShow'], $conf['contentToShow.'], 'contentToShow');
}
```

If this is not what you need, describe why you need the extension.

Comment: No what I want to know is how to insert all the content elements on the Right Column

Comment: What do you mean by insert? Please be more verbose.

Comment: Sorry if Im not being clear. im not sure how to word my problem. What I want is to add the content of the Right Column to the output of my Plugin. I dont know how to do that.

Comment: What is $conf["contentToShow"]?

Comment: in your main-method, you have main($content, $conf). $conf is the configuration array which is defined in typoscript

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, in the BE there is no easy way to manage programmatically the content of columns (if You are speaking about content zones, as I understand in Your question).

But You could map Your plugin through Typoscript. It will not be visible in backend in Your column, but the frontend will work fine.

And if Your plugin should render some content elements, there are already lots of examples how to do it through PHP :

- [TYPO3: How do i render tt_content text elements in my own extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71223/typo3-how-do-i-render-tt-content-text-elements-in-my-own-extensions)
- [Render CONTENT in PHP with TypoScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240625/render-content-in-php-with-typoscript)